# About Spring SecurityFilterChain 403 error

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to implement Spring security(6.1) and logic to authenticate with JWT token.

I want to implement this using Spring for the backend and Vue js 3.0 for the frontend.

But there is one problem. This is my SecurityConfig.class code.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    private static final String[] allowedUrls = {"/", "/login", "/signup"};

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
                        auth.requestMatchers(allowedUrls).permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                );

        return http.build();
    }


    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
```

I presented the Urls in the SecurityFilterChain to the authorizeHttpRequest, but the server returns a 403 error.

Also, this's my vite.config.ts code.

Without authorizeHttpReqeusts, vue's router fetches the URL just fine. However, when I specify authorizeHttpReqeusts, I still get a 403 error.

I am wondering what is causing the error and how to fix it.

Comment: Is this only an issue for POST requests now?

Comment: I haven't implemented the controller for post yet, and i move the urls, get a 403 error either way.

Comment: Spring Security provides a feature to defend against CSRF attacks. It works by checking whether the CSRF token exists or not, and if the error occurs only in the POST request, the 403 can be resolved by disabling the CSRF token when using JWT token

Comment: Enable spring security DEBUG or TRACE logs and update your question with them